# Implementation and extending interfaces from different packages

Tags: go, methods, interface, django-inheritance

I'm wondering, is it possible to extend existing interfaces? There is a simple code snippet which doesn't work.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

type Aaa struct {}

// Implementing io.ReaderAt interface
func (a Aaa)ReadAt(p []byte, off int64) (n int, err error) {
    return
}

// Extending it
func (a *Aaa) A() {
    fmt.Println("A")
}

func main() {
    list := [1]io.ReaderAt{Aaa{}} // Use Aaa object as io.ReaderAt type
    list[0].A() //Trying to use an extended type. << Error occurred here
}
```

> list[0].A undefined (type io.ReaderAt has no field or method A)

Is it a way to tell me that I can't implement interfaces from different package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's only telling you that `io.ReaderAt` doesn't have an `A()` method.

You need a type assertion to get an `*Aaa` out of the `io.ReaderAt`.

```
a := io.ReaderAt(&Aaa{})
if a, ok := a.(*Aaa); ok {
    a.A()
}
```

Interfaces don't need to be defined in any particular place, so if your code needs a `ReaderAtA` with those methods, you could define it yourself, and any `ReaderAtA` value would also be an `io.ReaderAt`

```
type ReaderAtA interface {
    io.ReaderAt
    A()
}


a := ReaderAtA(&Aaa{})
a.A()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0bl5djJ0im